# how to make the scrollwheel work in the window created by `vert term`?

Tags: cursor, mouse

OS version:

```
uname -a
Linux mydebian 4.19.0-14-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.171-2 (2021-01-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

vim verson:

```
vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jun 15 2019 16:41:15)
```

My terminal is LXTerminal,`set mouse=a` written into `.vimrc`.The scrollwheel in the middle of my mouse can move cursor up and down when to edit file with vim,and scrollwheel can work also--move cursor up and down in bash window.
Now i split the window into two parts for vim in the right and python interactive in the left.
`menu-system tools-lxterminal` ,and type `vim sample.py` ,enter into ex mode in vim and type `vert term`,two windows shown as below:

[image]

In the left window,go on to type `python3`:
[image]

Move cursor into the right window with `ctrl+w w`,and create many lines `print("ok")`--just for test,i can move cursor up and down by scrolling the scrollwheel in the mouse.
Copy all lines in the left window into the right window

[image]
I find that cursor in the left window can't be moved up and down by scrolling the scrollwheel in the mouse ,how to make the scrollwheel work in the window created by `vert term`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Neovim it works.

In Vim you must switch to `:h Terminal-Normal` manually first, e.g. `<C-\><C-N>`.